# overloadable binary operator expected

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Hi I have written this code but i do not know what is wrong with it

```
 namespace NumericsType
 {
     public float X,Y;

     public Vec2D_Struct(float x, float y)
     {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
      }

     // this line or rather 'implicit' give an compiler error 
     // CS1020: Overloadable binary operator expected
     public static implicit operator Vec2D_Struct(float x, float y)
     {
        return new Vec2D_Struct(x,y);
     }

      // other operator overload +, - 
 }
```

Is there some problem with the code? I am using C#

Thanks

Comment: How would you expect this to work? You're defining an implicit cast from one object to another, not two.

Comment: So we would have to use explicit command? Something along the line   public static explicit operator Vec2D_Struct(float x, float y) 
    {
        Vec2D_Struct d = new Vec2D_Struct(x,y);  // explicit conversion

          return d;
    }

Comment: An explicit cast is no different to an implicit cast in this respect. You can't just do `Vec2D_Struct a = 4,3;` or `Vec2D_Struct a = (Vec2D_Struct)4,3;`. C# doesn't support that.